# Loading Bitmap from ExternalStorage

Tags: android, bitmap, android-external-storage

This sounds like an easy task, but I can't upload a bitmap, I took with camera, into my app. Well, technically I can, but nothing get's displayed.

I use this code for taking pictures on `onClick`:

```
 count++;
            file = dir+count+".jpg";
            File newfile = new File(file);
            try {
                newfile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {}       

            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

Where

`dir` - `final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`

And this code for image loading:

```
        String location = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/" + count + ".jpg");
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(location);
        Bitmap mutableBitmap = myBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
        wv2.draw(canvas);
        tstImage.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
        text.setText(Float.toString(myBitmap.getHeight()) + " " + Float.toString(myBitmap.getWidth()) + " px");
```

Where

`count` - Integer that represents name of the image

`wv2` - custom WebView in which I draw canvas.

I do not think that these lines are relevant, but doesn't hurt to post additional info - you never know.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
wv2.draw(canvas);
```

This line displays text with dimensions of the image. I use it to check whether I load the bitmap.

```
text.setText(Float.toString(myBitmap.getHeight()) + " " + Float.toString(myBitmap.getWidth()) + " px");
```

When I run this code image does not get displayed, but text shows correct dimensions, which should mean that I do load the bitmap. What am I doing wrong? Where is the problem?

**[UPDATE]**

I think I'm making progress. Now I get outOfMemory problem and the app crashes.

```
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Pictures/" + count + ".jpg";
        File imgFile = new File(path);
        if(imgFile.exists()){
            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

           tstImage.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        } else {
            Log.d("Ciaren", "File doesn't exist");
        }
```

Comment: How you making sure that the image you are capturing from camera having the same path which you have defined above in code?

Answer (score 1):

OOM indicates that the image is way too big for memory to handle. There are two solutions here:

Either force your way through with `largeHeap="true"` in the manifest, which is okay, but can lead to problems in the future.

Or you can change the options of bitmap loading, so it takes less memory at a time. Thus the image will take more time to load, but remove the possibility of the crash. Plus, the time difference is barely noticable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using bitmap image get the uri or path and use picasso to load that image into imageView

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
switch(requestcode){
    case MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE:
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), seletedImageUri);
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(selectedImageUri).fit().into(imgDp);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it work? What does it do? And finally, I need to do some changes to the image(draw lines through canvas on it), so will it work with this?

Comment: Ok, then avoid picasso . I have modified answer now u can get bitmap image from uri and do your modification accordingly

Comment: Eclipse does not recognize `Picasso` nor `MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE`

Comment: compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Comment: add these lines to app gradle

Comment: I use Eclipse, not AndroidStudio.

Comment: i told you how to get bitmap image, you can avoid picasso

Comment: you can directly get bitmap image from uri , why you are first converting it to file then bitmap. refer my answer for solution

Comment: The problem is, I don't understand it. For instance, what is getContentResolver? It asks to create method().

Comment: I was using this in fragment, if you are using in activity use this instead of getContext(), getContextResolver() is a public method of Context class